# Command line options with optional arguments in Python

Tags: python, getopt

I was wondering if there's a simple way to parse command line options having optional arguments in Python.  For example, I'd like to be able to call a script two ways:

```
> script.py --foo
> script.py --foo=bar
```

From the Python getopt docs it seems I have to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`optparse` module from stdlib doesn't support it out of the box (and it shouldn't due to it is a bad practice to use command-line options in such way).

As [@Kevin Horn pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461942/command-line-options-with-optional-arguments-in-python/1462035#1462035) you can use `argparse` module (installable via `easy_install argparse` or just grab [argparse.py](http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/tags/r101/argparse.py) and put it anywhere in your `sys.path`).

#### Example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from argparse import ArgumentParser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser(prog='script.py')
    parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', metavar='bar', default='baz')

    parser.print_usage()    
    for args in ([], ['--foo'], ['--foo', 'bar']):
        print "$ %s %s -> foo=%s" % (
            parser.prog, ' '.join(args).ljust(9), parser.parse_args(args).foo)
```

#### Output

```
usage: script.py [-h] [--foo [bar]]
$ script.py           -> foo=baz
$ script.py --foo     -> foo=None
$ script.py --foo bar -> foo=bar
```

Comment: Is it possible to use argparse so that "script.py --foo     -> foo=None" becomes "script.py --foo     -> foo=baz"? Basically in my case --foo is exclusive with another flag --foo2 and I would like the value of --foo to be optional and use default value if it was not present.

Comment: @Ansis Atteka: As I understand it either `foo` or `foo2` must be present in your case, but not both. Is it correct? If so you could use commands instead: `script {foo [arg],foo2}` where `arg` defaults to `'baz'` if not set.

Answer (score 3):

Also, note that the standard library also has [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), a more powerful options parser.

Comment: optparse documentation explicitly states it does NOT support arguments with optional values (for good reason)

Answer (score 3):

check out argparse:
http://code.google.com/p/argparse/

especially the 'nargs' option

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an option in optparse that allows you to do this. But you can extend it to do it:

http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#adding-new-actions

Answer (score 1):

Use the [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) package.

Comment: see Triptych's comment to Ned Batchelder's answer: optparse documentation explicitly states it does NOT support arguments with optional values